# How to load image into RecyclerView Adapter of Android

Tags: android

In my application I should show image into `recyclerview` adapter. 
I have **2 APIs**. 
First API send to me images ids, and I should send this id to second API for get **base64** and then **decode** this **base64** to **bitmap** and again show this into `ImageView`! 
I write below codes, but per item first send API, receive **base64**, decode this and show into `ImageView` but when scroll items show me **lags**!

**My Adapter codes:**

```
class MyAdapter constructor(private val items: MutableList<Result>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ItemBinding
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private val userToken by lazy { GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(USER_TOKEN, "") }
    private var decodedBytes: ByteArray? = null

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    val formatter: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    lateinit var date: Date

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        context = parent.context
        return ViewHolder()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bind(item: Result) {
            binding.apply {
                //Title
                titleTxt.text = item.title
                //Date
                val dateStr = item.publishAt!!.split(" ")[0]
                date = formatter.parse(dateStr) as Date
                dateTxt.text = timeDiffer(date.time / 1000)
                //Like
                if (item.youLikeBefore!!) {
                    likeImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart)
                    likeImg.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.mystic))
                } else {
                    likeImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_line)
                    likeImg.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
                }
                if (item.likeCount!! > 0) {
                    likeTxt.isVisible = true
                    likeTxt.text = item.likeCount.toString()
                } else {
                    likeTxt.isVisible = false
                }
                //File
                if (item.file != null) {
                    when (item.file.type) {
                        IMAGE -> {
                            thumbImg.isVisible = true
                            thumbLoading.isVisible = true
                            ApiClient.getInstance().apisUseCase().getAvatarImage(userToken, item.file.id!!)
                                .applyIoScheduler()
                                .subscribe({
                                    thumbLoading.isVisible = false
                                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                        if (it.code() == 200) {
                                            if (it.body() != null) {
                                                decodedBytes = Base64.decode(it.body()!!.data!!.file, Base64.DEFAULT)
                                                thumbImg.load(decodedBytes) {
                                                    memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    thumbLoading.isVisible = false
                                })
                        }
                        VOICE -> {
                            thumbImg.load(R.drawable.img_voice)
                            thumbLoading.isVisible = false
                        }
                        VIDEO -> {
                            thumbImg.load(R.drawable.img_video)
                            thumbLoading.isVisible = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                //User
                if (item.user != null) {
                    doctorNameTxt.text = "${item.user.firstName} ${item.user.lastName}"
                }
                //Click
                likeImg.setOnClickListener {
                    onItemClickListener?.let {
                        it(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Result) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Result) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun addItems(items: MutableList<Result>) {
        this.items.addAll(items)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

First of all, I have question, **this way is True?** 
And I want to call this API just for once time! 
In my code per scroll call API and I used **Coil** cache for image loader but again get image from server does not call from cache!

How can I fix it?

Comment: I guess the image decode is happening in the UI thread? Probably you can try to decode thee image in a worker thread using Executors or Coroutines.

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA , Thanks you my friend, can you send to me code from Coroutines with my above codes? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per talk, I guess the image decoding happens in the UI thread.

So if this is the case, you can use `Executors` or `Coroutines`.

However, I am not a Kotlin developer so I am not familiar with `Coroutines` case. But it is similar to `Executors` so I will post the answer for `Executors` first.

**After the byte array is prepared,**

**Executors case:**

```
var uiHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    // Decode your byte array in another thread
    fun decodeAndLoad(file: ByteArray?) {
        val executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
        executor.execute {
            val decodedBytes = Base64.decode(file, Base64.DEFAULT)
            uiHandler.post {
                //TODO: Load your the byte array to image view here
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Coroutines case: (Updated)**

```
    fun decodeAndLoad(file: ByteArray?) {
        val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val decodedBytes = Base64.decode(file, Base64.DEFAULT)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                //TODO: Load your the byte array to image view here
            }
        }
    }
```

---

If possible, I think you shall use **Glide** and **Picasso** libraries to load the images in RV. Just input the URL and the image load (i.e., download by IO thread, load by UI thread) and cache will be done for you.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I have a question. Is it correct to call API in the adapter?

Comment: If you are talking about the image loading APIs you call inside bind callback, I think it will be fine if you take care the life cycle of the item holder. You shall be-aware that the same view holders will be used again when scrolling occurs. Though to avoid overhead and bug, I will recommend you to use libraries to do so.

Comment: Just think one scenario, if the item holder (Object Reference A) is downloading the image, if you scroll the Recycler View and now Object Reference A will now reuse to load another image, you will need to take care the concurrent issue by yourself.

Comment: While you use Glide, Glide will(shall) done this for you automatically. There's a Tesla so you don't need to invent the wheel again.